# How can i get the different value with code snippets below

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a problem on this because I always get the first value even if I click the last element of the table.

```
<table>
<?php 
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
?>
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="testId" value="{$i}"><td>
   <td><button class="testButton">Click Me</button></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

for js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".testButton" ).click(function(){
          var a = document.getElementById("testId").value;
          alert(a);
   });
});
```

how can I get each value?

Comment: You can't have elements with the same `id`, how about you make them a class?

Comment: var a=this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign values like `value="{$i}"`? How about changing it to `value="<?php echo $i; ?>"` Also assign unique IDs to each `td`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you actually need to `echo $i` on the value. And its also important to close the `<td>` markup properly.

```
<table>
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="testClass" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
   <td><button class="testButton">Click Me</button></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Then on JS, just traverse the previous `<td>` to get the input values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testButton').click(function(e){
        var a = $(this).parent().prev('td').children('input.testClass').val();
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PItmGJ)

Comment: Wow, I had basically exactly the same answer that you have here, with `class="testClass"` and everything. Although with a very slightly different way for the `testClass` value in jQuery. But I don't have to post it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign `id` for only one element.
in this case, you may want to assign different `id`s like below.

```
<td><input type="text" id="testId{$i}"><td>
<td><button class="testButton" data-target="#testId{$id}">Click Me</button></td>



$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".testButton" ).click(function(){
          var target = $(this).data("target");
          var a = $(target).val();
          alert(a);
   });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple targets? Like you have multiple inputs and just 1 button.